# Python Time series: extracting features on a rolling window basis

Tags: python, time-series, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

I have a long univariate time series, and before performing some machine learning models with it, I want to extract as many features as I can from the time series on a rolling-window basis.

As a quick example, for a window of size `10`, I would like to calculate statistics like mean and std deviation for the first `t=0:9` points in my dataset, and have those two results occupy one row in a some new feature table, and the next row in the table will have mean and std deviation calculated on points `t=1:10`, and so on and so forth, until the end of the data.

Is there an efficient way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are easy ways to do this in Python. My favourite would be to put the data into a Pandas DataFrame, which has a convenient method called [**`rolling`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) that will cycle over your data in a given frame-size and compute whatever you like on that block.

Let me show you an example - say we start with the following column of data:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                     
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.randint(0, 100, (20,)),
                           "B": np.random.randn(20)})
```

Look at the first 10 rows:

```
In [4]: df.head(10)
Out[4]: 
     A         B
0   63 -0.003947
1   55  0.442597
2    6  0.684125
3   17  0.968987
4   33 -0.018640
5   50 -0.579558
6   71  0.563125
7   31  1.417384
8    8  0.607813
9   36  0.186146
```

We can compute the rolling average over each column and save it back to the dataframe like this:

```
In [6]: df[["rolling_a", "rolling_b"]] = df.rolling(5).mean()
In [7]: df.head(10)
In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
     A         B  rolling_a  rolling_b
0   63 -0.003947        NaN        NaN
1   55  0.442597        NaN        NaN
2    6  0.684125        NaN        NaN
3   17  0.968987        NaN        NaN
4   33 -0.018640       34.8   0.414624
5   50 -0.579558       32.2   0.299502
6   71  0.563125       35.4   0.323608
7   31  1.417384       40.4   0.470260
8    8  0.607813       38.6   0.398025
9   36  0.186146       39.2   0.438982
```

You might notice that the first 4 rows contain `NaN` values (Not a Number). This is because the `rolling()` method will let the `mean()` method work an a window-size smaller than 5 (in our example). There are a lot of options in the `rolling()` method that you can experiment with.

You can do the same above for single column of a large dataframe like this:

```
>>> df["rolling_some_column_name"] = df.some_column_name.rolling(5).mean()
```

You can also apply just about any function to the rolling frame - not just `mean()`.

Comment: Raises error: `"None of [Index(['rolling_a', 'rolling_b'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`